# How get bearer token with requests from python

Tags: python, web, token

I'm trying to replicate a login to a page with python and the requests module but I need a token bearer.
This site doesn't require a login password connection but just an event code (wooclap.com)
I cannot find when the token is recovered by looking at header and json responses.
If you can help me
Thanks

Comment: Kindly share the response you get when you send a response and a code snippet of how you're making the request to give clarity to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend finding it using DevTools in your browser (F12).

In network you can see the login request mainly under headers and response. I've used this to implemented it below in python for you.

```
import requests

# Set the URL of the login page
url = "https://app.wooclap.com/api/auth/local/login"

# Set the login credentials
data = {"username": "< !!enter username here!! >", "password": "< !!enter password here!! >"}

# Send the login request and store the response
response = requests.post(url, data=data)

# Get the JSON response body
json_response = response.json()

# Get the AWT token from the JSON response
awt_token = json_response.get("token")

# Set the URL of the resource you want to access
url = "https://app.wooclap.com/public/events"

# Set the authorization header of your request, using the Bearer scheme
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {awt_token}"}

# Send the request and store the response
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Error on line 13: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Answer (score -1):

once you put in a event code check the network tab on you're chrome console there should be a request wich returns the token. either in the reponse header or the json,

Comment: After the GET for the html there are 3 GETs for json to `/api/config` `/api/user` and `/api/events/...`, the first 2 have in their Header `authorization : bearer null`, and the 3rd have `authorization : bearer <token>`
I can't find where to get the token because nothing happens in between and json responses doesn't contain the token

Comment: Looking at the javascript I found an Auth.getToken() function and a authUrl variable
is it possible that the JS makes invisible requests ?
is it possible that the JS generates the token ?
And how to obtain it ?

Answer (score -3):

To send a GET request with a Bearer Token authorization header using Python, you need to make an HTTP GET request and provide your Bearer Token with the Authorization: Bearer {token} HTTP header

Comment: This is nonsense and doesn't make any sense given the current question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).